# Light by light cross section using equivalent photon approximation (EPA)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, computational-physics, scattering-cross-section

I'm trying to understand how to do a numerical calculation of the light by light cross section utilizing the Equivalent photon approximation (EPA). I'm considering two incoming electron beams of energy E ($\sqrt{s_{ee}} = 4E^2$), both which radiate photons with distribution $f(x)dx$ where $x = E_{\gamma}/E$ is the fraction of energy carried away by a photon, and $f(x)$ is the Weizsäcker-Williams distribution . These photons then scatter and produce two outgoing photons with invariant mass $s_{\gamma\gamma}$, so the hard process is $\gamma\gamma \rightarrow \gamma\gamma$.

I am following reference https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.07548 where they compute (with a slightly different hard process)
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\sigma}{ds_{\gamma\gamma}} = \frac{1}{s_{\gamma\gamma}}\int_{x_{min}}^{x_{max}} dx_1 f(x_1)f\left(\frac{s_{\gamma\gamma}}{x_1 s_{ee}}\right)\sigma(s_{\gamma\gamma})
\end{equation}

where $x_{max} = 1 - \frac{2m_{e}}{\sqrt{s_{ee}}}$ and $x_{min} = \frac{s_{\gamma\gamma}}{s_{ee} - 2m_e \sqrt{s_{ee}}}$ are the maximum and minimum energy fractions. Notice there is only one integral over a single energy fraction, $x_1$, because with $s_{\gamma\gamma}$ fixed the other photon energy fraction is fixed by $x_2 = \frac{s_{ee}}{x_1 s_{\gamma\gamma}}$.

Does this seem like the right way to compute this? I ask because when I compute my cross section by hand and compare it with MadGraph@aMC_NLO cross section with basically no phase space cuts and the same $f(x)$ I get a wildly different answer. The answer for the scattering cross section of the hard process is the same, but not the total cross section.